Вывод числа из массива
for i in range(len(a)):
if a[i]%5==0:
    b.append(a[i])
    b.sort

Из этого кода нужно вывести второе максимальное число, помогите пожалуйста.

В питоне отступы важны..

Что у вас не получается? Помните, что учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при  решении задачи (для этого нажмите [edit]). Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

a = [1, 10, 5, 25]
b = list()
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] % 5 == 0:
        b.append(a[i])
b.sort()
if len(b) >= 2:
    print(b[-2])
else:
    print("Нет второго максимума")



Спасибо большое!


list() -> [] 2) range(len(a)) -> a и a[i] -> i.


@wchistow, в коде автора видно, что он хочет итерироваться по индексам. А насчёт создания списка "скобками", вместо конструктора, вообще не понял, почему это плохая практика.
